# intelliSense 'No members available'

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, intellisense

using inheritence and generic in c++ ,this problem appeared to me:
this is my abstract base class

```
    template<class Type>
struct A
{
Type info;
};
template<class Type>
class base
{
protected:
     A<Type>* ptrA;
public:
    virtual void func(Type X) = 0;
    void func(Type X) 
     {
         ptrA->info = x;         //no Errors occured
     }
};
```

and this is the derived

```
template<class Type>
class derived : class base<Type>
{
public:
  void func(Type X)
  {
    ptrA-> info  = x ;       // this is the problem 

  }
};
```

the problem appeared to me at the function definition of the derived class : that i cannot access the
member that ptrA refrenced ,,, any help ,please

Comment: typo: `x` vs `X`

Comment: TL;DR - you need to add `this->` to tell the compiler that `ptrA` is indeed an inherited member of a base class.

Comment: If your using an old IDE you could try to update to a newer where this bug is fixed.

Comment: @Surt what bug?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The useless message, that doesn't tell the user anything.

Comment: @Surt oh my bad. Its in the title, I was only scanning the question and had no clue what you mean.